# Save new record trough relationship results in Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'created_at'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have 2 models with many-to-many relationship,
when it try to retrieve the data everything works fine, so the relationship is working properly. but when i'm trying to save new data trough the relationship i get

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'created_at', table 'dlist.dbo.dlist_employee'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (SQL: insert into [dlist_employee] ([dlist_id], [employee_id]) values (2, 26))
```

Here my code:

```
   $new_employee = new Employee(array('name' => 'name','username' => 'username','email' => 'email'));

   $dlist = Dlist::find(2)->employees()->save($new_employee);
```

From what i understand the created_at and updated_at fields  filled automatically. And since i can extract the data successfully (mening the relatinship are defined correctly) - what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the save script are attempting to insert a "null" into the created_at column in the database table.

Try setting your "created_at" column in the database to "nullable".

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i did understand the error - but i didn't understand why was it happening. Is relationship table supposed to be without created_at?

Comment: Generally no. Since a relationship is its own entity/model, and has it's own table, it should be utilizing the created_at/updated_at rows. Perhaps you have $timestamps = false; defined in the model, or the driver for MSSQL is not functioning correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Please check : [this regarding timestamps](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#timestamps)

Does your model has `public $timestamps = false;` ?
If yes, then you need to manually take care of the timestamps

Also check if the migration ( if that's the system you used to create your table ) has the correct columns definitions for created_at updated_at